# Apache Mod-Rewrite rule condition required to Dynamic Query String positions

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have an  URL like `http://localhost/test.html?param1=a&param2=b&param3=c`
I want the rewrite condition to check query parameters param1,param2 and param3 can be in any order..it could be like below

```
http://localhost/test.html?param3=a&param2=b&param1=c
http://localhost/test.html?param2=a&param3=b&param1=c
http://localhost/test.html?param3=a&param1=b&param2=c
```

Please help me how can i rewrite conditions for this Query String .. I can write all the combination with [OR] condition but is there any best way to  achive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)param1=[^&]*(&|$) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)param2=[^&]*(&|$) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)param3=[^&]*(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^test\.html$ target-uri-goes-here? [NC,L]
```